# Inserting non-ASCII characters into pdf with Python reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, utf-8, reportlab, non-ascii-characters

My code is supposed to insert a text into a pdf template. The variable text is

```
text = u"Gęślą JaźńZażółć"
```

First, I create an empty pdf, then a Canvas instance with the file as a parameter, then incorporate text with 
`canvas_instance.drawString(10, 10, text.decode('utf-8')` 
and save it. 
And my original pdf file indeed contains a text in a right position - but I get ASCII characters + neat black squares instead of non-ASCII letters.
I have tried setting font to 'Times-Bold' and 'Helvetica' but they don't seem to work, either.
I have a coding declaration in my python file, too:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

How would I be able to insert text into a pdf template?

Python: 2.7
libs: reportlab, pyPdf
ubuntu 14

Comment: Seems I should use setFont to set a font to some font supporting Polish, cause text = decode('utf-8') is too little...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, a ttf supporting Polish solved this problem:

```
name = u"{} {}".format(unicode(mydata['firstname']), unicode(mydata['lastname']))   
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Theano', '<path>/TheanoOldStyle-Regular.ttf'))

can.setFont('Theano', 16)

can.drawString(175, 400, name.decode('utf-8'))
```